# netezza nzsql export query results into csv file

Tags: netezza, nzsql

when i export query results into csv using netezza nzsql commndline , the o/p is printed to file in fixed length format. i.e if a col is defined as 4k length its printing out 4k length sting irrespective of lenght of the stored string in that field. As a result , the o/p file is getting huge due to lot of extra spaces. is there a way to get around it? I tried trimming columns , replace(field,' ','')  but it didnt help.

command i am using :

nzsql -d {dbname} -u {username} -h {host} -c "select * from table_with_90_columns " -t -o output.csv

Comment: You need to specify a delimiter, and I think you will find this covered in this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251399/how-to-output-a-file-using-tab-delimiter-in-netezza-nzsql)

Comment: nzsql has a default delimiter of | . I see the fixed length o/p even if i go for a different delimiter.

Comment: I am curious whether it is possible to grab header sql types in addition to header names when using nzsql ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using nzsql to output delimited data, specify a delimiter of your choice with the -F option, and specify unformatted output with the -A option.

Or, use external tables as they will be quite a bit faster for data of any significant size.